# Click elements by classes with specific text in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, phantomjs

I'm trying for 2 hours now to find a selector to choose form a list in the facebook share dialog : 
 [facebook share dialog](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=966242223397117&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/dialog/return/close&display=popup&href=http://www.isearchforjob.com/)

(i don't use thier api for the restricted access to some features )

```
var casper = require('casper').create({

    pageSettings: {
        loadImages:  false,        // The WebPage instance used by Casper will
        loadPlugins: false,        // use these settings
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0'
    },
    logLevel: "info",              // Only "info" level messages will be logged
    verbose: true


});
var fs = require('fs');
var dyn = null;
casper.start('http://facebook.com/login.php', function() {
    // search for 'casperjs' from google form
   console.log("page loaded");

   this.test.assertExists('form#login_form', 'form is found');

   this.fill('form#login_form', { 
        email: 'email', 
        pass:  'pass'
    }, true);

    this.wait(1000, function() {
        casper.capture('login.png');
        console.log("screen captured");
    });
});
    casper.thenOpen('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=966242223397117&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/dialog/return/close&display=popup&href=http://www.isearchforjob.com/', function() {

    console.log("debug loaded");

    this.wait(1000, function() {
        casper.capture('debug.png');
        console.log("screen captured");
    });

    if (this.exists('span._55pe')) {
        this.echo('span._55pe exists');
        this.click('span._55pe');
        this.echo('\n\nspan._55pe clicked\n\n');
    }   

    this.wait(5000, function() {
    if (this.exists('li[class="_54ni _42ym _2n3i __MenuItem"] > a._54nc')) {
        this.echo('li[class="_54ni _42ym _2n3i __MenuItem"] > a._54nc exists');

        this.echo('\n\n li[class="_54ni _42ym _2n3i __MenuItem"] > a._54nc clicked\n\n');
    }   

    });


    this.wait(10000, function() {

        fs.write('2.htm', this.getPageContent(), 'w');

        casper.capture('clicked2.png');
        console.log("screen captured");
    });
});
casper.run();
```

the first click works perfectly here is a screenshot :

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l13Yf.png)

but the second click wont :

```
this.click('li._54ni _42ym _2n3i __MenuItem');
```

results in the same selector for all the list so it's useless

this is the HTML:

```
<li class="_54ni _42ym _2n3i __MenuItem" role="presentation">
    <a class="_54nc" href="#" role="menuitem">
        <span data-reactroot=""><span class="_54nh"><span>Share in a group</span>
```

Is there any chance I can get the selectors by text? "Share in a group"

And is it possible to simulate the down arrow key in this case?

Comment: *"And is it possible to simulate the down arrow key in this case?"* - What exactly does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classes are all written one after the with the class selector:

```
this.click('li._54ni._42ym._2n3i.__MenuItem');
```

You can also use [an attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to match an element with a specific attribute string (works for any attribute and not just `class`):

```
this.click('li[class="_54ni _42ym _2n3i __MenuItem"]');
```

You can even mix those:

```
this.click('li.__MenuItem[class^="_54ni _42ym"]');
```

Finally, you probably want to click the link in a list item:

```
this.click('li[class="_54ni _42ym _2n3i __MenuItem"] > a._54nc');
```

Comment: Artjom B. thanks a lot for your effort , unfortunately i get the selector right but i couldn't click it , i edited my question so you can see the full view .

Comment: Then you have to find a different way to disambiguate the different list items. This is the best I can do with the limited markup example you provided.

Comment: i edited my question this is the link for the whole page : 
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=966242223397117&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/dialog/return/close&display=popup&href=http://www.isearchforjob.com/

Comment: You don't necessarily need to accept an answer if it didn't help you or solve your problem. If you found an answer yourself, then you can post your own answer here, but remember that answers should be complete.

Comment: i manage to find a solution cause of you're answer , you gave me the right path to follow , i used xpath to get it done `this.click(x('//span[text()="Share in a group"]'))`
you can add it to your answer :) , but i'm stuck for 2 days with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045035/casperjs-fill-input-without-name i tried everything :/ , found out that's you're specialist in this headless browser any help will be appreciated , thanks .